# How do I get my 4TB HDD size (OS and BIOS shows only 2TB=1.8TiB)?

Tags: hard-disk, disk, bios

I switched my server from an Ubuntu 18.04 32bit to a Debian 10 64bit system. Both of the hardware uses BIOS and can not boot into UEFI mode.

So I got both of them an HDD for the system with an MBR partition table. For the data, I use 4TB HDD with GPT and one ext4 file system. It works on the old machine; however, on the Debian machine, it shows me the disk (the 4TB disk from the Ubuntu system and a newly bought 4TB disk) as 2TB disks.

How do I get the whole capacity of 4TB?

---

#### Outputs

`# fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2 TiB, 2199023254528 bytes, 4294967294 sectors
Disk model: WD...
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3...


Disk /dev/sdc: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: V...    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe...

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  ...


Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB, 2199023254528 bytes, 4294967294 sectors
Disk model: S...
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

gdisk and sfdisk gives similar output.

Comment: Most TB sized drives use newer 4K sectors. Or it should show 512/4k not 512/512. How are you connecting drives? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
USB adapter may show drive as 1/8 size, use SATA port for 4K drives Did you use gdisk or newer fdisk to create partitions on gpt drives? Old versions of fdisk did not support gpt.

Comment: Including the disk models would be useful

Comment: What is a disk model? FIrst I used a SAS connection, then I changed it to sata. Same result. But I got the hint, that the controller might not be able to handle 4TB harddrives. Even in the BiosSetup it showed Size: 1,80TB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that my BIOS sees 1.8TiB too. It seems to be a old controller, therefore I must buy a new controller or even a new computer.